# Confusion about sort and Swap Functions while sorting from a file alphabetically

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, swap

Okay, Previously I had an error with this code with the parameters not matching, now I am having an issue with rewriting my sort and swap functions. I am confused on which variable names to use. I have tried every way I can think, but I keep getting errors. I have done all the reading in both of my assigned books, and this assignment is due sunday, but I am trying to work ahead and get it done with. So if anyone could point me in the right direction for re-writing my sort and swap functions, I would be very gracious. The exact lines of code I am confused about are as follows:

```
 void swap(salesTran A[], int i, int j)
    {
    int temp;
    temp =A[i];
    A[j] = A[j];
    A[j] = temp;
    return;
    }
    void sort(salesTran A[], int size)
    {
        for(int p=1; p<size; p++)
        {
            for(int c=0; c<size-p; c++)
            {
                if(A[c]>A[c+1]) A (A,c,c+1);
            }
        }
        return;
    }
```

My entire Program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

struct salesTran {
string name;
double quantity,price;
};

void swap(salesTran A[], int i, int j);
void sort(salesTran A[], int size);

ostream& operator << (ostream& os, salesTran A)
{os << A.name << "\t" << A.quantity << "\t" << A.price;
return os;}
istream& operator >> (istream& is, salesTran& A)
{is >> A.name >> A.quantity >> A.price;
return is;}

int main()
{
   salesTran data[250];

ifstream fin;
fin.open("sales.txt");
ofstream fout;
fout.open("results.txt");

int index = 0;
fin >> data[index];
while(!fin.eof())
{
index++;
fin >> data[index];
}

sort(data, index);

for(int j=0; j < index; j++)
{ 
cout << data[j] << endl;
}

return 0;
}

void swap(salesTran A[], int i, int j)
{
int temp;
temp =A[i];
A[j] = A[j];
A[j] = temp;
return;
}
void sort(salesTran A[], int size)
{
    for(int p=1; p<size; p++)
    {
        for(int c=0; c<size-p; c++)
        {
            if(A[c]>A[c+1]) A (A,c,c+1);
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: The due date of the assignment isn't relevant. But the errors you get (including which lines they refer to) would be very relevant.

Comment: @jogojapan 

when i try to do "salesTran temp;" I get an error saying salesTran is undefined. That's why I originally tried using int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your swap function, `temp` should be an object of type `salesTran` object, not an `int`.

Comment: when i try to do "salesTran temp;" I get an error saying salesTran is undefined. That's why I originally tried using int

Comment: @user2133925: I'm sorry, I don't believe you.  If your code is as you've shown it, in one file, in the order you've shown it, and you simply made the change I suggested, you will not have that error.  You have some other errors in other functions, but after the change I suggested, the swap function is fine.

Comment: Okay, I'm sorry I must have messed something else up. I fixed all the erorrs with my swap function. Thank you so much for your time. I am getting an error with my sort function that says pointer to function type. I will take a look at my sort function to try to fix the error. If you would like to point me in the right direction that would be great. Thanks!

Comment: @user2133925: In addition to the change suggested by Potatoswatter, your sort function uses the 'greater than' operator, `operator>` on `salesTran` objects.  Why are you expecting that to work?

Comment: I am sorry. That was a dumb syntactical mistake. I have adjusted the code to:

if(A[c] > A[c+1]) swap(A,c,c+1); now I am getting a no operator matches error under the "<". I am looking up this error now. Thank you

Comment: I can't upvote till I have 15 rep, I will bookmark and come back when I am able to. Thank you again =P

Answer (score 1):

```
A (A,c,c+1);
```

You are attempting to call `A` as a function where you apparently want `swap`.

Also be aware that there are functions `std::swap` and `std::sort` which do what you want, but more efficiently.

Comment: I have read up on the Std: :swap and std: : sort, but since I am unaware or have any experience with them I am sticking to this code for now, but hopefully in the future I will learn how to implement that.

Comment: @user2133925 There are numerous errors and issues in the posted code. If you can do your own research and want to learn C++, you're better off not relying on your instructor's C++ expertise. You can call `swap( A[c], A[c+1] )` and `sort( data, data + index )` to use the standard functions. If you found any of this helpful, please upvote, and upvote Ben too. (I know you didn't ;v) )

Comment: I don't think he has enough rep to upvote.  [It requires 15](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-up).

Comment: @Potatoswatter I will, Thank you for your time. I'm sorry this is my first time using stackoverflow and I'm still trying to figure it all out!

I changed my code and fixed my sort function. Now I just have one error in my swap function.
            if(A[c]>A[c+1]) swap(A,c,c+1); Im getting an no operator matches for ">"

Comment: @Potatoswatter I can't upvote till I have 15 rep, I will bookmark and come back when I am able to. Thank you again =P